# Moved internal hard drive to external USB 3.0 hard drive. Now I can't boot windows

Tags: windows-7

I recently upgraded to an SSD in my laptop. When I removed the old hdd, I placed it in an external enclosure in case I needed to boot from it and restore data.

I would like to pull of my power settings to put on my new hard drive from the old install. Dell sets up some sort of settings that gets me far better battery life than the defaults.

However, when I boot windows from the USB, I get a BSoD with the 7B error. From my experience, the 7B error comes when you swap IDE/AHCI in BIOS, but as this is USB, those options aren't available.

How can I boot windows from my external, failing that, how can I extract a power plan from a non-booted windows.

Comment: I'd put the old drive back into the computer, boot, make a note of the power settings then install the new drive and proceed from there.

Comment: I have a Dell XPS, it's a pain to get to the hdd. You have to remove the front bezel around the keyboard.

Comment: Well, pain or no pain... you should have gotten everything you needed from that running install of Windows before you pulled the drive off the controller, instead of just assuming that you could boot to that install regardless of how it was connected to the computer.  Or... if you prefer, you should have ASKED if this would work *before* you did it, rather than asking why it didn't work *after* you did it.  Consider the extra effort, or rather the pain, to be the lesson learned.

Comment: @Malfist Windows 7 installation cannot be booted from a USB device, go to the Dell site, sometimes they have software to set the Dell power plan, post your specific model of Dell please.

Comment: @Moab   You write "Windows 7 installation cannot be booted from a USB device,"  <--- Windows 7 Install can run from USB and install to a hard drive.   Perhaps you mean the windows 7 itself cannot run from USB / be installed to USB, but that doesn't seem to be correct either.  There is a program called WinToUSB this guy does it for Win 7  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niRYtf3Yzm0     It is even possible to boot XP from USB   (Not Bart PE or Win XP PE, but XP itself, it seems. The youtube video producer Britec has done it here.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=re1_ude0fhE

Comment: My comment was 3 Years ago, things change over time.