# How to make a formerly internal (sata) Windows 7 hdd boot over USB 3.0

Tags: windows-7, usb, boot

I am getting a Windows Failed to start message - implicating a hardware change. And rightly so - I moved my internal laptop drive to an external USB 3.0 enclosure.

Startup repaire runs into problems 'Startup Repair offline' - I can see advice online for *installing* *to* an external drive but not for moving a drive.

I want to do something very similar to

- http://reboot.pro/topic/9196-tutorial-boot-windows-7-from-usb-hard-disk-by-karyonix/

except I want to use an existing hdd, not a fresh one, and I can't find any tutorials with the specific "NT 6.x fast installer, BootDriverFlags, PollBootPartitionTimeout" tutorials it made reference to.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: [Read what *Moab* wrote](http://superuser.com/questions/406627/moved-internal-hard-drive-to-external-usb-3-0-hard-drive-now-i-cant-boot-windo#comment463083_406627). Passage of time will not magically change what the same OS version can or cannot do. Win8 Enterprise supports the [Windows To Go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_To_Go) feature for the first time.

Comment: If you read the question I said "it looks similar to" and if you read it, you will find that it is not a duplicate - different symptoms, and all answers relating to power profiles. Maybe I made it too easy for @Sathya to dupe this.

Comment: I've reopened it.

Comment: Thank you @Sathya, I am sorry if I was being a little belligerent.

Comment: I still appears that Windows 7 does not support doing this.  I had a similar need my month long search for a solution ended up making me decide its not supported for good reason.